# Validating whether a String is either starting or ending with a specified character using Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need to validate an input String such that it is allowed to have characters 'E', 'W', 'N', 'S' (or their lowercase counterparts) only at either the beginning or at the end of a string(not both). The character will be followed by digits. The character cannot be between digits. Also, if it is present at the beginning then it cannot be at the end(and vice versa).

I was able to come up with this regex: `[wWeEnNsS]{0,1}\\d+` that only checks the characters at the beginning. But how do I make sure that if it is present in the beginning then it can not be at the end?

Following are examples of valid inputs:

```
w234,
W234,
E234,
234w,
234
```

Invalid inputs:

```
w234w,
2w34,
ww234,
we234,
w234e,
w
```

Comment: Do you have to use 1 regex or can you use a combination?

Comment: I think `^(?![wWeEnNsS](?:.*[wWeEnNsS])?$)(?!.*\d[wWeEnNsS]\d)(?!.*[wWeEnNsS][^0-9]).+` will work for you. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/m44g2e/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use an alternation using the case insensitive mode matching:

```
^[ewns][0-9]+$|^\d+[ewns]?$
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^(?:[ewns]?[0-9]+|\\d+[ewns])$";
```

- `^[ewns][0-9]+$` Start of string, match 1 of the listed chars and end of string
- `|` Or
- `^\d+[ewns]?$` Start of string, optionally match 1 of listed chars and end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ttJ5py/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/xvKTwq)

Comment: I came up with the following solution which is almost similar to yours: ```([wWeEnNsS]?(\\d+)$)|(\\d+[wWeEnNsS]?$)```

Comment: If you don't anchor your pattern at the start, you might have partial matches https://regex101.com/r/qesn9f/1